# Memoir and tcolorbox A <box> was supposed to be here

Tags: errors, memoir, tcolorbox, update

After installing the new updates I get these errors while compiling my documents

*A <box> was supposed to be here.*

*A <box> was supposed to be here. \setcounter*

deleting as much as possible left me with this document

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

tekst

\end{document}
```

which gives this error

*A <box> was supposed to be here. \end{document}*

replace "memoir"with book or article no error, removing twocolumn no error

I updated everything and reinstalled MikTex but the problem remains.

any ideas?

Comment: Same problem on an updated TeXLive installation.

Comment: If one adds `\tracingall` before `\end{document}` one gets some gibberish with hooks. Maybe some LaTeX kernel change plays a role here?

Comment: hm, I get it too. I will look.

Comment: No problem with a non-updated installation.

Comment: @PeterWilson I've forced auto loading mparhack under two column mode. Without it the side marginpar lands on are not always correct. Memoir relies on a kernel macro to tell us if we're in col 1 or 2. That macro sometimes fails.

Comment: I have uploaded a new version of mparhack which contains Frank's fix, so tomorrow it will hopefully work again.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be an incompability between mparhack and the shipout/background hook.

You can as workaround until this is fixed suppress the loading of the package:

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{mparhack}{}
\makeatother
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

blub

\end{document}
```

The problem is that mparhack redefines `\hb@xt@` in the output, and this command is used in various places, beside others in `\put`, and this means that the code in the shipout/background hooks fails. So another work around is this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put (0,0){}}
\makeatletter
\long\def\put(#1,#2)#3{%
  \@killglue
  \@defaultunitsset\@tempdimc{#2}\unitlength
  \raise\@tempdimc
  \hbox to\z@{% <--- instead of \hb@xt@
    \@defaultunitsset\@tempdimc{#1}\unitlength
    \kern\@tempdimc
    #3\hss}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatletter  
\begin{document}

blub

\end{document}
```

Comment: Either the mparhack needs to be updated or the "fix" it provides really ought to be in the kernel.

Comment: @daleif I'm just discussing this. Perhaps we will add something to firstaid. (but long term mparhack should disappear ...).

Comment: @daleif but is it "really" a fix? that is not a comment on the current issue, but the "hack" in there is rather bad and had resulted (not surprisingly in issues before as can be seen by the package attempts to alter eso-pic)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach no, a bandaid rather, it is clear there is a problem, but as far as I could gather there currently is no real solution to this problem

Answer (score 5):

As Ulrike said, the problem here is that the package `mparhack` attempts to patch the kernel command `\@dbloutputcol` and inject some code into it. To make its life easier it simply redefined \hb@xt@ which is used there and replaces that under certain conditions (when the first argument is `\columnwidth`) with its own code --- if not it tries to execute the original code (which is basically `\hbox to`). Unfortunately that breaks very badly in other places where the kernel and package use `\hb@t@`, i.e., whenever it is used and has to be expandable, for example inside `\put` where the code looks like this

```
   \raise \hb@xt@ ...  % means \raise\hbox to ...
```

After `mparhack` has acted this now looks like

```
   \raise \def\mph@tempa{}\hbox to
```

an `\def` is not a box hence the error.

Midterm `mparhack.sty` needs a correct patch (or should vanish eventually), short term, here is a firstaid that we should apply from the kernel side until the package gets fixed. I didn't do much just made sure that `\hb@xt@` remains expandable and expands to `\hbox to` normally (there are better ways to address this):

```
\makeatletter
\def\mph@outputdblcol{%
    \def\mph@chk@dcl{0}%
    \def\hb@xt@##1##2{%
        \ifx##1\columnwidth
            \mph@step@cnt\mph@chk@dcl
            \protected@edef\mph@tempa{%
                \noexpand\write\noexpand\@auxout{%
                    \noexpand\string\noexpand\mph@setcol{%
                        \romannumeral\mph@chk@dcl:\noexpand\thepage%
                    }{%
                        \noexpand\string\noexpand\mph@nr%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
            \mph@orig@hb@xt@##1{##2\mph@tempa}%
        \else
            \mph@orig@hb@xt@##1{##2}%
        \fi
    }%
    \mph@orig@outputdblcol
    \def\hb@xt@{\mph@orig@hb@xt@}%
    \ifnum\mph@chk@dcl=0\relax
    \else
        \ifnum\mph@chk@dcl=2\relax
        \else
            \mph@error{\string\@outputdblcol}%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\AddToHook{package/after/mparhack}{\let\@outputdblcol\mph@outputdblcol}
\makeatother

%----- above needs to happen before mparhack is loaded or rather fixed there


\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

tekst

\end{document}
```

As a final remark, especially also in the light of the claims made in [Are the latest TeXLive updates failing to provide backwards capability?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595287/are-the-latest-texlive-updates-failing-to-provide-backwards-capability) in the comments:

- yes with more activity, bug fixes and extended functionality, new releases of LaTex may break things (any change has that ability)
- but it very often simply shows hidden bugs or misuses that are lurking in many of the  aged packages ... seriously you can't alter something as low-level as `\hb@xt@`and change its semantics and then say it is LaTeX's fault if this breaks when all we do is using it as defined by the kernel. And in that particular case the authors must have seen the problem in the past as they tried to fix it for eso-pic which does (more or less) what is now offered as a standard functionality in the kernel.
- so yes things can break, but seldom silently, but so far such breakages have been mended by the package authors or by us (and usually for the better) because typically the true cause was a lurking issue that just showed its face

### Update 2021-05-04

`mparhack`got the necessary patch and it showed up on TL by now. This means that the problem should be gone. As a side-effect `mparhack` should now also work correctly in older LaTeX releases, for example, in TL18 where it broke the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark,mparhack} 
\begin{document} X \end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, the last three items do not match reality, at least not the one I am experiencing. Can it happen that users load packages that are a bit murky, perhaps without their knowledge? Yes. Does it help if the kernel gets changed in such a way that old files break and one is much more likely to get a very different output on the arXiv, say, than on an up-to-date TeX installation? I would say "No". In particular as this is a rather recent phenomenon.

Comment: @user241086 sure that can happen (though "a bit murky" is a question of opinion). The problem with a bit murky is that any change in the kernel  (the \hb@xt@ is a perfect example) can have that effect and yes, no one wants that ,which is why we chaise after such issues and normally get them resolved, which is why on arXiv you shouldn't get that  problem (often) and if then only for a short period of time on few documents, but other than doing nothing ever there is not way to avoid such intermediate hickups (at least none that I know of --- if you have a receipe please tell me).

Comment: Well, I understand that you might have some greater goal in mind, but please accept that some long-term LaTeX users see an increased rate of cases of backward incompatibilities. Some of them lead to errors in L3 syntax, which some of these long-term users like me do not really understand (and as it happens here), and sometimes the output changes. The files in which this happens are, in my case, either very long (we are talking about hundreds of pages) or of confidential nature, so not shareable, and even worse, I do not understand the "modern" error messages (so can't localize the issue well).

Comment: @user241086 as daleif wrote above in a comment to the question, the error has been triggered by a change in memoir he made, not by a kernel change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So "The problem seems to be an incompability between mparhack and the shipout/background hook." is incorrect? Please, we are not playing games here.

Comment: @user241086 no the problem is as I explained an always existing bug in mparhack, showing up when a picture environment is executed as part of the OR (that could have happened before but now it always happens if shipout hook has code in it as it spans a picture). How can you guide against such a redefinition of core internals? It would have broken in the past if some class used atbegshi + mparhack and in a number of other cases, so it was just lurking there to be discovered and it is not playing games to say the change was the memoir one and a similar one could have happened a few years back.

Comment: @user241086 no the two are incompatible. But a dangerous package that is not loaded is not a problem, using it gives errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am sorry, you are contradicting yourself. Sure, there is a murky package around. Nonetheless, from the perspective of a user, there is a document that worked until the kernel underwent changes. That is, a working document became nonworking. Of course, you have a very different perspective, but put yourself in the shoes of someone who has a deadline and wants to submit a document in time. Maybe you can agree that, at least from the perspective of such persons, all these recent changes are not uncontroversial.

Comment: @user241086 are you sure you are listening to arguments? In that particular example it was *not* a kernel change that caused the problem, it was a change in the used class file and it could have happened any time in the last 15 years if a similar change could have been made.

Comment: @user241086 As to the perspective from the user: why did he or she upgrade their system other then to get changes incorporateded? And for any change you can construct a document that afterwards fails. If you are on a deadline you don't change your running system regardless of whether that is TeX or anything else. Tell me one recent or not so recent kernel change that left murky packages dry for a longer period of time I'm not aware of one and if you obey cautious update policies as anybody should, I can't see why any was or is controversial.

Comment: I am sick of the wording you are using, and of the pseudo-arguments, and, yes, the lies. ("It was not a kernel change.")  Just one thing: are you proud of the volume the `firstaid` package has assumed? Is this how it is meant to be? Is is also "not a kernel change" which made it necessary. Getting back to how it all started, I say this to both of you: I am not an idiot. Just keep the misinformation for yourself, I am out of here.

Comment: @user241086 good then.  No lies involved in my post. Try \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark,mparhack}
\begin{document} X \end{document} in TL18 or earlier just as a simple example. Am I proud about first aid? Yes. It contains 4 fixes for other packages one of which is fixing a bug that is in bigfoot since ages one is for bidi and one for dinbrief last supported in 2000 --- so not a bad record at all imho.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach that fix to `mparhack` seems incomplete, try adding `twocolumn` to the class.

Comment: Or rather, the fix is not triggered out side twocolumn mode.