# Are the latest TeXLive updates failing to provide backwards capability?

Tags: texlive, update

I have noticed that there have been several posts on TeX-SE saying that after updating to the latest TeXLive that documents that used to be processed OK now report errors. I haven't updated so all is fine with me but now I'm extremely reluctant to update (and perhaps won't). I thought that LaTeX documents from years ago would always be processible but that seems to have gone a little to the wayside. --- GOM

Comment: There was never any such guarantee for LaTeX, highlighted most notably by the UTF-8 default in 2018(?).

Comment: It is definitely not. If you get error messages, you can consider yourself lucky. The tricky situations are those in which you do not get error messages, but the document gets screwed up without any complaint, which seems to happen more frequently in recent updates. This is particularly "exciting" when this happens in connection with long documents (e.g. books or lecture notes, for which one is typically reluctant to check the output line by line) and/or sensitive documents such as recommendation letters, and/or if you have a deadline.

Comment: as the question was triggered by mparhack: the documentation explicitly states that it hooks into core LaTeX commands "and might break with future LaTeX versions that change
these commands."  If you use such a package don't be surprised when happens what their documentation announce.

Comment: @HenriMenke there were essentially no user level backward compat issues reported for the utf-8 change.

Comment: @user241086 it would be really helpful if you substance that claim you make here. I'm not saying that this can't happen but it is certainly not a common occurance to the best of my knowledge and if you really come across something like that it would help if you open a bug report at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues to help resolve such a case rather than just claiming it here.

Comment: @HenriMenke we provided backwards compatibility for the UTF8 change so I don't think that is a case in point of Peter's question.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Control your wording: "rather than just claiming it here". Did you just forget about the `memoir` example that just surfaced? At least I have no interest in having rude interactions, if you want others to post issues somewhere do not treat them like you do. It would be really helpful if you were sticking to the facts, rather than suggesting that others make "claims".

Comment: @user241086 you state above that one is lucky if one gets error messages but that LaTeX screws things up without them, so the mparhack issue --- which is not a LaTeX kernel change issue --- is not an example for that statement as it gives you an error. All I asked you was to substance such statements by providing bug reports if something like this happens and not just hint/claim/indicate. So what please should have have written? If you tell me the wording I'm happy to write a new comment with the same substance. But I don't see where I was not sticking to facts as you now say/claim/indicate.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Sooner or later you will find someone who is patient enough to provide you with more examples, but the tone of your messages does not really encourage others to do so. At least I am a bit shocked about what happens here. There is a post by someone who appears to understand LaTeX well, and there seems to be a collective to say that they are seeing ghosts, and everything is great. Just so that you know, I do not think that participating in this makes any sense. Have a nice day!

Comment: sadly I think this question meets the "opinion based" close reason for the site. The question itself is reasonable but the question (and answers) just attract hostile non-productive comment threads. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, it is possible to switch back, but if I remember correctly that requires user interaction.

Comment: @HenriMenke not really. Any document using non ascii characters should have already declared the encoding used so `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` or whatever, those documents work without change. So the only documents requiring action were documents that were using non ascii characters without declaring an encoding and just relying on using that subset of the T1 font eencoding that is the same as latin 1.  I saw exactly 1 end user query about a document affected by that. Despite several people warning us against making that changit proved to be exte, remely event free and compatible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry that you felt that you had to delete your answer as I found it very credible and useful. It is a great shame that one commentator, only providing opinions, has ruined a useful discussion.

Answer (score 7):

I think an answer here has several parts.

First, TeX Live (TL) is a collection of code from *many* people, and the maintainers of TL itself only provide a small part of this - they are mainly 'collectors'. As such, other than changes in *e.g.* `tlmgr`, TeX Live makes no statements about compatibility.

If we look at binaries, there is some overlap with the TL team, for example with pdfTeX. That is maintained pretty conservatively, but other binaries perhaps have more freedom. LuaTeX would be the most obvious example.

I'll not go further with hyphenation patterns than pointing out that they can and do change, and alter line breaking without any warnings.

The bulk of TeX Live is of course macro packages. There, changes are down to individual authors. Taking an example which hasn't happened just yet (at time of writing), I will soon release a major update to `siunitx` - v3.0. I have various significant changes I wish to make, and I have to balance up

- Simply calling it a 'new' package - workable but burns through names, means
  existing users don't get any benefit
- Making breaking but necessary changes, which as far as possible I will issue
  warnings for
- Providing a way to 'fall back' to the v2.0 code - doable using `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`

On balance, I feel a new major version after a period of beta testing is the right approach. However, I know there will be some user impact: I can't really avoid that *if* I want to be able to maintain the code and fix bugs.

That takes us to the issue that as a macro expansion language, we can't stop other people using 'internal code'. In my example, I'm making API changes that I *know* I can document and test. But I'm also changing internals: that is much harder to test against what individuals may have done.

As such, the best we can do is to document changes, test and aim to provide routes to roll back where there are issues.